# #!/usr/bin/env not working as environment

Tags: python, macos

I am working on MacOS to learn the environment

```
#map_it.py - launches a map in the browser using an address from the command line or clipborad
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webbrowser, sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #Get the address from the command line
    address = "".join(sys.argv[1:])
    print(address)
#todo:get the address from the clipboard
```

I set shebang at top of the script which did not work as I intended

```
$ map_it.py test
-bash: map_it.py: command not found
$ map_it test
-bash: map_it: command not found
```

After I changed `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and `#!/usr/bin/env`,
It report the identical error.

How could I fix such a bug?

Comment: is your script executable? If not, try chmod +x map_it.py

Comment: I changed mode "-rwxr-xr-x  1 me   staff   443 Aug 17 15:56 map_it.py*"  it still report "$ map_it.py test
-bash: map_it.py: command not found" python map_it.py test works @Harpe

Comment: See l'L'l's answer below, I missed it before but in order to refer to a script in your current folder, you have to give the path with ./, where . stands for your current folder. Note that this is a shell-specific issue and not related to python.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do either:

```
$ ./map_it.py test
```

or

```
$ python map_it.py test
```

...otherwise you are indicating the script is a system installed command.